# Как добавить в буфер обмена ссылку из атрибута href?

Tags: javascript, html

Имеется ссылка и кнопка. Как при нажатии на кнопку скопировать содержимое именно href? Может какая то библиотека есть JQ?

```
    <a href="https://www.google.com" class="link"></a>
<a class="click-btn">Нажми для копирования ссылки link</a>
```

Comment: [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/)

Comment: На enSO есть развёрнутый [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На enSO уже был похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript).

```js
const $target = document.querySelector(`.link`);
const $button = document.querySelector(`.click-btn`);

$button.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  navigator.clipboard.writeText($target.href).then(() => {
    console.log('Async: Copying to clipboard was successful!');
  }, err => {
    console.error('Async: Could not copy text: ', err);
  });

});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: .5rem;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" class="link">Ссылка</a>
<a class="click-btn">Нажми для копирования ссылки link</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Жалко рейтинг пока меньше, но голос пишут что учитывается!))